# could not read data in post method in php

Tags: php

After successful payment,  page post data to my server page. There  i can only read data by

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
  {
   file_put_contents($filename, "$key: $value\n", FILE_APPEND);        
  }
```

this php code and write to text file
but do not get any data by normal post variable.

For example status key sent through post data if i called through $_POST['status']   i do not  get any value through it.

so what happen here i am out of ideas.
So please guide me here to get post data.

Documentation define data send in post method and encrypt type in application/x-www-form-urlencoded

**My php file code Where post data redirect to**

```
<?php
  session_start();


echo "post Data:"; print_r($_POST);   //Nothing Show


$filename = "webhook_data2.txt";

foreach($_POST as $key => $value)

{

    file_put_contents($filename, "$key: $value\n", FILE_APPEND);


}

file_put_contents($filename, "----------\n", FILE_APPEND);

?>
```

**This works and out put of text file is as below :**

```
buyer_name: xxxx xxxxx xxxxx
offer_slug: xxxx xxxxxx xxxxx
currency: INR
custom_fields: {"Field_42842": {"value": "xxxxx@xxxx.org", "required": "on", "type": "char", "label": "Email Mentioned on the Form"}, "Field_85492": {"value": "XXX XXX XXX", "required": "on", "type": "char", "label": "Student Name"}}
status: Credit
quantity: 1
variants: []
payment_id: MXXXXXXXXXXXX
buyer: xxxxx@xxxx.org
amount: xxxx.00
fees: 0.xx
buyer_phone: ############
offer_title: ###### #### #########
mac: ******************
unit_price: ##.00
```

Comment: where is your HTML form? provide it

Comment: Try: `var_dump($_POST)` or `print_r($_POST)` and see if anything is set..

Comment: are you sure that "status" is the correct key name?

Comment: already try var_dump($_POST) or print_r($_POST) but nothing in it

Comment: @simon i just type it for example. i have try the keys which write to text file but do not get any data

Comment: If that's the case then you are not submitting your form values right @Avinash

Comment: Provide more code. If `print_r($_POST)` shows an empty array, your `foreach` shouldn't work either. So there is probably something else going on in your code

Comment: @simon  i use a third party payment gateway server so when a user make payment successfully they redirect to my server page, where all relative data are in post method. foreach works and data also coming from their side as i can write data to text file by following code :$filename = "webhook_data2.txt";

    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)

    {

        file_put_contents($filename, "$key: $value\n", FILE_APPEND);
        

    }

    file_put_contents($filename, "----------\n", FILE_APPEND);

Comment: @Avinash please read my answer and check specially raw post reading

Comment: @Avinash I understand that. But when the `foreach`-loop works, directly accessing the values by `$_POST['key']` should also work. We need more code to see what is going on.

Comment: @simon, i have added what u need.

Comment: @Avinash does `print_r($_POST)` show nothing at all or an empty array?

Comment: @simon nothing at all

Comment: @Avinash this is very strange. Did you check if there are any errors or warnings?

Comment: @simon there is no error or warning show in page. Is there any other way to check please tell me.

Comment: @Avinash add these lines on top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL);`
and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Check if post is send

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $data = '';
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
          $data .= "$key: $value" . PHP_EOL; 
    }
    //write data
    file_put_contents($filename, $data);  
} else {
    die('POST REQUEST IS NOT SEND');
}
```

1. Getting data and then writing it to file once is faster than writing it in loop.
2. If post is not request type(not send) then it will fail and it will display 'post request is not send'
3. If 2 appears then check if your form method is set to **POST** and action url is correct.

Also if your POST data is raw then you can read it from stream named `php://input` with functions that read from stream for example

```
file_get_contents(`php://input`);
```

to read RAW post and save it you can use code below

```
file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents(`php://input`));
```

When your request is in RAW form for example JSON/XML it won't be mapped to $_POST automatically you need decode the input by your own for example if it is json then use json_decode, if it is xml then you can use DOM or simplexml. From manual:

`$_POST`

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.

Comment: data is send by other server which redirect to my page name receiver2.php. Where only i am able to write data to text file name data2.txt but can not get data by normal $_POST variable.  i have already try this file_get_contents(`php://input`); but no result to me.

Comment: if this does not work then data is not sent to this file

Comment: but from here i can write data to text file. Please see my edited post. There i am post both the file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually sometimes $_POST is empty for various reasons. When that happens to me it always work to read `php://input` 
like `$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");`

$postdata is now json-string that you can convert to an array like:

```
$arr = json_decode($postdata, true);
```

Then you should be able to do:

`foreach($arr as $key => $value)
  {
      file_put_contents($filename, "$key: $value\n", FILE_APPEND);

  }`

Comment: i have try these things just look at it    :      $post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
print_r($post_data);    --------- nothing in it .                                    $rawPostBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$postData = json_decode($rawPostBody, true); print_r($postData );   ------------ nothing in it     .